# ImageJ Color Threshold Macro

Tags: image, macros, imagej

I want to create a macro running "Analyse Particles" on different images.
The problem is that I have to Color Threshold before running the Analyse command.
The generated macro using the "Macro" button does not work correctly, it generates a binary image, therefore the values Skew, Curt, Mean, StdDev, etc are useless.

My images are already preprocessed, so the required threshold settings are pretty simple. 
[image: Threshold settings]

Answer (score 2):

The *Threshold Color* plugin internally converts your RGB image to the HSB color space, so you can't interactively use *Analyze Particles* because there is no single threshold value set.

You should indeed generate the binary image, and then use the "**Redirect to**" option in *Set Measurements* to measure on your original image.

Please also see the [user guide](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:Set-Measurements...) and several [discussions about color analysis on the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/tags/color-analysis).

But if you already pre-process the images, why don't you make them 8-bit gray scale? That would simplify the measurements and save memory and/or processing time.